# MFC Ribbon - alignment issue(s)

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

Create a standard App with ribbon, then add this to the CMainFrame::InitializeRibbon() at the appropriate place.

```cpp
// Create panel

CMFCRibbonPanel* pMyPanel = pCategory->AddPanel(L"Test", m_PanelImages.ExtractIcon(27));

// Add wide combobox with short label to panel

m_pMyCombo = new CMFCRibbonComboBox(ID_MYCOMBO, false, 150, L"Short:");
m_pMyCombo->AddItem(L"Just some test data");
pMyPanel->Add(m_pMyCombo);

// Add narrow edit with longer label to panel.

CMFCRibbonEdit* pMyEdit = new CMFCRibbonEdit(ID_MYEDIT, 50, L"Longer label:");
pMyPanel->Add(pMyEdit);
```

Issue 1:
The combobox "sticks" to the top of the panel.
The edit control "sticks" to the combobox.
There is about 1/3 of the height unused.

Is there a way to make these 2 controls use the full height ? I can use pMyPanel->SetCenterColumnVert(); But the 2 controls are still stuck together although they're now vertically centered. What I'm really after is that there is more or less even spacing above and below the controls.

Issue 2:
this looks like

```
Short: [______________________|v]
Longer label: [___]
```

which isn't really looking nice.

I can call SetJustifyColums() but this results in

```
Short: [______________________|v]
Longer label: [___]
```

which may seem OK enough, but if the length of the labels reverses it gives:

```
Longer label: [______________________|v]
Short: [___]
```

which isn't really looking OK.

I'd really like to get this to like you'd normally make a dialog. Labels left aligned and controls left aligned also.

```
Short: [______________________|v]
Longer label: [___]
```

How can these issues be solved?